# pagination with the Angellist API

Tags: php, pagination

I am a little stuck on how to show the Angellist API records on the page with pagination.

I succesfully got the first 50 records of the Angellist API showing on the page. When i change the number of $page to 2 and print $data, i do get the 50 records of page 2.
But now i don't know how i can do that automatically so i can get the pagination going.

This is the code i have until now:

```
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ?  (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$jsonurl = 'https://api.angel.co/1/jobs/?page=' . $page;
$url = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$data = json_decode($url,true); 
$total = $data['total'];
$per_page = $data['per_page'];
$current = $data['page'];
$last_page = $data['last_page'];
?>
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="pagination">
            <?php 
                $i = 0;
                while($page < $last_page) :?>               
                    <?php echo "<a href=\"/jobs?page=".$page++."\"\>Next 50</a>";                                       
                endwhile;

            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope this is sufficient information for some help, but if you need more info i'm happy to give it.

Answer (score 0):

You could a ternary with `$_GET` -

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ?  (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
```

and then your url would look like

```
yourpage.php?page=2
```

And you can create a next link -

```
echo "<a href=\"yourpage.php?page=".$page++."\">Next 50</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the code with yours.I can see that the url has the page loaded, but still the same 50 records keep showing. What am i missing? I edited the code above.

Comment: Please tell me the solution of this i also faces this issue